# getting request parameter in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

i need to read request parameter from a lambda function.iam configure  Body Mapping Templates on my api gateway get method like this

```
{
    "val1": "$input.params('val1')",
    "val2": "$input.params('val2')"
}
```

my Lambda function code is

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement

  var val1 = require('querystring').parse(event.params.val1);
  var val2 = require('querystring').parse(event.params.val2);

    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda' + val1 +'test'+val2);
};
```

But when testing my api method,  i got error *"Process exited before completing request"*  with log

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'val1' of undefined
```

What is the actual issue related with this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `event.params` is undefined.

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
var val1 = require('querystring').parse(event.val1);
var val2 = require('querystring').parse(event.val2);
```